# Powershell simple script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a simple script that is made to search the members of a group introduced as a parameter, and it works properly:

```
$param1=$args[0]
Get-ADGroupMember "$param1" | ft name,objectclass,samaccountname
```

But when I try to run this other script (very similar funtionality), it doesn't show anything,, just blank:

```
$param1=$args[0]
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*$param1*"' -Properties LastLogonDate,PasswordLastSet | ft Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,PasswordLastSet
```

Someone could help me, what am I doing wrong?

PD: When I run the second command manually, replacing $param1 with a letter, it works as intended.

---NEWS---

I have tried this variation of the second script and idk why but it works:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity "$args" -Properties LastLogonDate,PasswordLastSet | ft Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,PasswordLastSet
```

May it be, that the option "-Filter 'Name -like "$args"'" it's what is causing all the trouble?
It's very strange because, the second script doesn't show an error, it just doesn't show nothing and goes to the next prompt line. (I have already tried to replace the $param1 with $args like in the last example and it's the same output, nothing)

Thanks in advice :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex, Try this instead.  `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$($param1)*'" -Properties LastLogonDate,PasswordLastSet | ft Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,PasswordLastSet`